Node js promise all multiple api calls in loop
I'm new to Node js. Here I'm calling multiple api calls in Async. But I want to return promise once all calls are finished.
function getChunkBatchDetailsResponse$(id,
  baseUri,
) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
   
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': `${configJSON.apigeeBaseUrl}/batch`,
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
      },
      body:

    };
    request(options, function (error, response) {     
     
      if (response.body) {     

        for (let i = 0; i < totalNumberOfChunks; i++) {
        
          chunksArray.push(formData.buffer.subarray(chunkStart, chunkEnd));
          chunkStart = chunkEnd;
          chunkEnd = chunkStart + chunkSize;
          if (chunkEnd > totalFileSize) {
            chunkEnd = totalFileSize;
          }
        }
        let promiseAll = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < chunksArray.length; i++) {
          let chunkNumber = i + 1;

          //return new Promise((resolve) => {
          getChunkUploadResponse$(          ).then((response) => {
           
            logMessage(
              `Upload '${id}' took ${endUploadTime - startTime}ms to complete`,
            );

          });
          // resolve('chunk file uploaded');
          //});
        }
        // Promise.all(promiseAll);
      }

      resolve(batchMessage);
    });
  });

}


function getChunkUploadResponse$(
 
) {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
   
    request.post(
      `${configJSON.apigeeBaseUrl}/UploadChunk`,
      {
        formData: {
          file: {
            value: buffer,
            options: {
              filename: directory.name + '.zip',
            },
          },
        },
        headers: {        
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
        },
      },
      (err, response) => {
        logMessage('err performing batch chunk upload.');
        logMessage(JSON.stringify(err));
        logMessage('response performing batch chunk upload');
        logMessage(JSON.stringify(response));

        if (err) {

          resolve({
            id,
            directory: directory.path,
            message: err,
            code: 500,
          });
        } else if (response) {
          const statusCode = response.statusCode;
          this.batchMessage = {
            id,
            directory: directory.path,
            message: response.statusMessage,
            code: statusCode,
          };
          if (statusCode === 201) {
            try {
              this.batchMessage.batch = JSON.parse(response.body);
              logMessage('Successfully performed a batch chunk upload');
              resolve(batchMessage);
            } catch { }
          } else if (statusCode === 413) {
            resolve({
              id,
              directory: directory.path,
              message: JSON.parse(response.body),
              code: 500,
            });

          }
          else {
            let message = '';
            try {
              message = JSON.parse(response.body);
            } catch {
              message = '';
            }
            batchMessage.message = message;
            logMessage('message performing batch chunk upload.');
            logMessage(message);
          }
          resolve(batchMessage);
        }
      },
    );
  });
}

If all calls are success should return  success. Should return error if one call also fails.

Please [edit] your question to contain actual, valid code. What you have here is not. See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

If all calls are success should return  success. Should return error if one call also fails. How can I return promise?

That's exactly what Promise.all is intended for.

Your code has lots of undefined variables, like totalNumberOfChunks, chunkStart, chunkEnd, chunkSize, totalFileSize, endUploadTime, startTime, batchMessage (and potential confusion with this.batchMessage), configJSON,  buffer , formData, directory, ...etc, ...etc, and then a  call of getChunkUploadResponse$() without arguments, ... this code cannot work.

You can use Promise.all to wait for all promises to resolve.
function getChunkBatchDetailsResponse$(id, baseUri) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': `${configJSON.apigeeBaseUrl}/batch`,
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`,
      },
      body: // Add your request body here
    };
    request(options, function (error, response) {     
      if (error) {
        reject(error); // Reject if there's an error
        return;
      }
      if (!response || !response.body) {
        reject(new Error('No response or empty body')); // Reject if no response or empty body
        return;
      }
      
      const chunksArray = [];
      const totalNumberOfChunks = /* calculate totalNumberOfChunks */;
      const chunkSize = /* calculate chunkSize */;
      let chunkStart = 0;
      let chunkEnd = chunkSize;
      const totalFileSize = /* calculate totalFileSize */;
      
  
      for (let i = 0; i < totalNumberOfChunks; i++) {
        chunksArray.push(formData.buffer.subarray(chunkStart, chunkEnd));
        chunkStart = chunkEnd;
        chunkEnd = chunkStart + chunkSize;
        if (chunkEnd > totalFileSize) {
          chunkEnd = totalFileSize;
        }
      }
      
      const promiseAll = chunksArray.map(chunk => {
        return getChunkUploadResponse$(chunk); // Call getChunkUploadResponse$ for each chunk
      });

      // Wait for all promises to resolve
      Promise.all(promiseAll)
        .then(() => {
          resolve(batchMessage); // Resolve with batchMessage once all uploads are successful
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error); // Reject if any upload fails
        });
    });
  });
}

Hopefully I understood your question correctly and this helps. Best of luck! :)

Ilia Popov, Thank you

My pleasure to be able to help! :)
